# Visualize Point Cloud with Open3d with XYZRGB Values (Python)

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, open3d

I have a 2 arrays- one with XYZ coordinates and one with RBG values. Both are n x 3 shown below. When I try the code below to visualize the geometry with the respective RGB values, I get the error in Python. How can I visualize the points with their respective colors with Open3d? Many thanks!:

**Inputs:**
'mypoints' array of n x 3, and 'colors_dbscan' array of n x 3.

[image]
[image]

**Code attempted:**

```
import open3d as o3d
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mypoints, colors_dbscan], window_name='DBSCAN')
```

**Error:**

```
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-bca02a8c2eb2>", line 1, in <module>
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries(pc)
TypeError: draw_geometries(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (geometry_list: List[open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50, point_show_normal: bool = False, mesh_show_wireframe: bool = False, mesh_show_back_face: bool = False) -> None
    2. (geometry_list: List[open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.Geometry], window_name: str = 'Open3D', width: int = 1920, height: int = 1080, left: int = 50, top: int = 50, point_show_normal: bool = False, mesh_show_wireframe: bool = False, mesh_show_back_face: bool = False, lookat: numpy.ndarray[float64[3, 1]], up: numpy.ndarray[float64[3, 1]], front: numpy.ndarray[float64[3, 1]], zoom: float) -> None
Invoked with: <__main__.PointCloudAnalysis object at 0x0000022A5C683A48>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first convert array of points to point cloud format.

And than assign color to point cloud.

This [issue](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/614#issuecomment-430044242) is what you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30543309)